# Posting users credentials in jersey & restygwt

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jersey, basic-authentication, resty-gwt

I want to make a post request with user credentials.

My server side is ready and I have tested it using postman. Something just like this: ***http:/localhost/8080/appname/oauth/token/grant_type=password&username=bill&password=secret.***

I want to send this url by clicking on a certain button in my restygwt client, how to send this request to my server side from my restygwt client's button?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. Please update your post with a clear question, state exactly what issue you are facing and what you have already tried to resolve the issue.

Comment: _"I want to send this url"_ - No you don't. You do not want passwords or any other confidential information in the URL. You should post that information in the request body.